# Why doesn't pytest load conftest.py when running only a subset of tests?

Tags: python, pytest

Here is my API test directory layout:

```
api_tests
├── conftest.py
└── query
    └── me_test.py
```

Contents of conftest.py:

```py
print("CONFTEST LOADED")
```

Contents of me_test.py:

```py
"""Tests the "me" query"""

def test_me():
    assert True
```

If I simply run `pytest`, everything works:

```
================================================= test session starts =================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.8.5, pytest-6.1.0, py-1.9.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /home/hubro/myproject, configfile: pytest.ini
collecting ... CONFTEST LOADED
collected 3 items                                                                                                     

api_tests/query/me_test.py .                                                                                    [ 33%]
lib/myproject/utils_test.py .                                                                                   [ 66%]
lib/myproject/schema/types/scalars_test.py .
```

Notice "CONFTEST LOADED" is printed. Great! However, this test run also picked up all my unit tests, which I don't want. I want to separate my test runs into unit tests and API tests, I don't want to run them all in one go.

However, if I simply run `pytest api_tests/`:

```
================================================= test session starts =================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.8.5, pytest-6.1.0, py-1.9.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /home/hubro/myproject, configfile: pytest.ini
collected 1 item                                                                                                      

api_tests/query/me_test.py .                                                                                    [100%]

================================================== 1 passed in 0.00s ==================================================
```

Now the right tests are run, but the conftest.py file wasn't loaded... How come?

---

I am using Pytest 6.1.0 on Python 3.8.

---

EDIT: Alright, I found an acceptable workaround. I can override INI file options through the command line with the `-o` option. This works:

```
poetry run pytest -o "testpaths=api_tests"
```

However, I would very much like an answer to the original question so I'm not going to delete it.

Comment: The local `conftest` plugin will be loaded one way or another. The difference is just in the collection, thus the print will be swallowed on the second invocation.

Comment: @hoefling Oh shit, you're right...  Go ahead and write that in an answer and I will mark it as correct...

Comment: Don't worry, `pytest`'s support of nested conftests is rather tricky and has multiple unwanted side effects, this being one of them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `conftest` plugin will be registered in both invocations, the only difference being the registration stage. If in doubt, add the `--traceconfig` argument to list the registered plugins in order of their registration:

```
$ pytest --traceconfig
PLUGIN registered: <_pytest.config.PytestPluginManager object at 0x7f23033ff100>
PLUGIN registered: <_pytest.config.Config object at 0x7f2302d184c0>
...
=================================== test session starts ===================================
...
PLUGIN registered: <module 'conftest' from 'path/to/conftest.py'>
...
```

In the first invocation, the `conftest.py` won't be found immediately since it's down the test root path, so it will be loaded while `pytest` discovers the tests. In the second invocation, `conftest.py` is located in test root, so it will be loaded even before the test session starts (after the plugins passed via `-p` arg and registered via `setuptools` entrypoint are loaded). Running `pytest -s` (with output capturing disabled) should reveal the custom print, located above the `==== test session starts ====` line.

If you want the print to be identical between the two invocations, put it in a suitable hook. For example, to always print `CONFTEST loaded` after test collection finished, use:

```
# api_tests/conftest.py

def pytest_collectreport(report):
    print("CONFTEST loaded")
```

There are other options available for custom output placement; best is to check out the list of available hooks under [Hooks](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference.html#hooks) in `pytest` reference.